# After getting significant results in ANOVA i got an Error in TukeyTukeyHSD in R

Tags: r

I have a 350 plant genotypes that have been tested for resistance against a disease in the field. i used ANOVA to see if there is differences between the genotypes reactions. 
Here is my code:

```
mydata=read.csv("population1ohneNAs.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
mydata
summary(mydata)
```

ANOVA worked out

```
myAnovaResults=aov(mydata$Tiefe~mydata$Prüfglieder, data = mydata)
summary(myAnovaResults)
```

when I tried to get TukeyTest results i got this error:

```
resultTukey=(TukeyHSD(myAnovaResults,"Prüfglieder",ordered = TRUE))
# Error in order(means) : argument 1 is not a vector
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Maybe it should be `myAnovaResults=aov(Tiefe~Prüfglieder, data = mydata)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will learn how to include a reproducible example for next time. This Time it worked out as you suggested (: (: